# Guardar informacion de select del mismo name adicionales PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario donde donde esta un SELECT con las opciones: DNI, PASAPORTE y OTRO, donde el usuario puede agregar mas opciones, puede ser que solo eliga una opción o hasta 15.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El select lo tengo de esta forma

```
<select class="form-control" name="txtDoc[]" required>
  <option value="DNI">DNI</option>
  <option value="PASAPORTE">PASAPORTE</option>
  <option value="OTRO">OTRO</option>
</select>
```

El formulario envía a guardar.php

donde recibe la información

```
    $doc = $_POST['txtDoc'];

    for($i=0; $i<count($doc[$i]); $i++){             
        $obj->guardar($doc[$i]);
            if($obj){
                //redirige hacia principal
            }else{
                //mandamos mensaje de error
            }
    }
```

la función guardar es la siguiente:

```
        public function guardar($doc) {
            $sql="INSERT INTO tanla(doc) VALUE (?)";
            try{
                $smt=$this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $smt->execute(array(
                    $doc
                    ));
            }catch(Eception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

El problema esta en que solo guarda el primer elemento, cuando seleccione varias opciones

y me da el siguiente error

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in guardar.php on line 41
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in guardar.php on line 41

Linea: 41 del archivo guardar.php

```
for($i=0; $i<count($doc[$i]); $i++){
```

Comment: ¿Que es `$seccion[$i]`?

Comment: `$doc = $_POST['txtDoc'];`  no es un array si lo haces de esta manera. por eso te muestra el error deberías 

`$doc= array(); // creo el array`
``$doc[] = $_POST['txtDoc']; // agrego el valor``

Comment: agrega el javascript que duplica/remueve el select tal vez le esté cambiando el name, en guardar.php podes ver que es lo que viene con un `<?php var_dump($_REQUEST);?>`

Comment: je parece que es mas simple `for($i=0; $i<count($doc[$i]); $i++){` estas contando el primer elemento, prueba con `for($i=0; $i<count($doc); $i++){`

Comment: hice lo que @WilfredoAleman y al hacer el  var_dump me sale todos los datos, pero no guarda, no hace lo del for

Comment: Vale si te ha funcionado  lo siguiente que debes hacer es recorrer el array con un `foreach` como sugerencia y el codigo quedara mas limpio `foreach ($doc as $key => $value) {
    $obj->guardar($value);
            if($obj){
                //redirige hacia principal
            }else{
                //mandamos mensaje de error
            }
}`

Comment: en la funcion guardar `public function guardar($doc) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO tanla(doc) VALUE (?)";
    try{
        $smt=$this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $smt->execute(array(
            $doc
            ));
            return true;
    }catch(Eception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}`

Comment: recuerda publicar tu respuesta par ayudar a futuros programadores. Un saludo